# How to access a WCF SOAP service with wsHttpBinding from Linux?

Tags: linux, web, interface, soap

I am trying to consume a WCF SOAP service with wsHttpBinding from Ubuntu.

Whatever I try, PHP, SoapUI, Java, I'm running into problems with wsHttpBinding features not being implemented. Changing it to BasicHttpBinding or disabling security features is not an option.

**NOTE:** It pretty much doesn't matter what language is used. Is there a SOAP client/framework/library that supports all these features and runs on Linux?

I'd prefer a scripting language as this is supposed to run as a cronjob, but right now anything that works is appreciated.

There are similar questions from months/years ago, but they are unresolved or solved by changing the server side, which like I said is not an option here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try GSOAP. you can find here more information about the functions: 
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html. it is a very complex package and it takes some time to learn the entire stack and how to use the generators and additional modules but it works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The OP is asking a very generic question. EG any package/software/tool that can process WCF WebServices with wsHTTPBinding. the tool is called gsoap.i edited the answer for more clarity.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It's technically a correct solution, but using a "complex package that takes some time to learn" is not an option only to get access to an API. We ended up changing the SOAP service and I can only advise against using SOAP at all. It's overcomplicated for what it does and there are no good implementations for most languages, although that might change with WCF now being open source.